# singularity at differential equation with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I can't solve this differential equation by `ode45` beacause it has sigularity.

```
xy"=3xcos(x)+sin(x) ; x(0)=0 , x'(0)=0
```

can you help me to write `ode45` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sinc(x)` function, which is defined as `sin(π*x)/(π*x)`, except at `x=0` where its value is 1. So, you can rewrite your ODE as:

```
y'' = 3*cos(x) + sinc(x/π)
```

which `ode45` shouldn't have any trouble solving.

Comment: Don't you need to throw a `π` in there somewhere? `y'' = 3*cos(x) + π * sinc(x/π)` maybe?

Comment: @CanSpice: You're right; I forgot the factor of π on the outside.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the factor of π should be there, since `sinc(x/π) = sin(x)/x`, which is the term being replaced.

Comment: Okay, so it was right the first time. I can't say I'm a fan of the normalized sinc function, but that's what's implemented in Matlab.